# Unable to remove my bathroom recessed lock

Tags: lock

I want to repair my recessed lock, it broke some time ago and I have to replace it, but I have an issue. This is a bathroom lock and, I cannot remove it from the door, because the "bathroom spindle" is stuck in the mechanism with some metallic jaw.

Here are two photos to understand the setup:

[image: context of the lock situation]
[image: more context of the lock situation]

And here is a zoom at the thing preventing me from removing the bathroom spindle:
[image: the culprit]
[image: the culprit 2]

Do you have any idea how to remove it, should I just hammer the spindle until it moves? It seems a bit rusty as well!

Comment: It looks like a screw head, have you tried unscrewing it?

Comment: It’s not a screw head, it’s the end of the spindle just to be able to open it from the outside if someone is stuck inside. See this for example https://www.cdiscount.com/pdt2/6/2/8/1/300x300/auc0732771940628/rw/tige-carree-de-8-mm-en-acier-solide-longueur.jpg

Comment: If not a screw head, then remove the other knob and tap the spindle with a hammer and punch.  Some knobs have a small screw locking them to the spindle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who might come on this topic later (if you ever search for this), this is in fact a model sold at the BHV (bazar de l'hôtel de ville) in Paris. You can find the exact same mechanism and the only solution to remove the part is to force because the metallic jaw can be gripped on the metallic bar. This is a bad mechanism...

I broke a porcelain ring by removing it. But you can buy spare parts at the BHV. See [the complete kit](https://www.bhv.fr/p/paire+de+rosace+condamnation+de+condamnation+porcelaine+de+limoges+blanc-essentiels+du+bhv/24025586/378) for example.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post your answer!

Comment: The link doesn't allow access to the page.